# NodeJS and Express - substring search

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, encryption, aes

in the following code I use Express JS and AES256 encryption to encode and decode simple text strings, based on a predefined key.
Specifically, the Express JS web server allows me to display certain elements depending on the content of the URL.
For example, if the URL was abc.com/encryption?code=hi, the server would show me the encrypted text. If, however, the URL was abc.com/decryption?code=NN(GFSO&8UOUSDB, I would get the plain text.
The problem arises during the encryption: when the encrypted word contains special symbols ($, &, +, ;, ?) recognized by HTTP, the decoding fails at all.
The validation conditions seem to be logically correct, but I can't always obtain a valid result.
Thank you very much.

```
const aes256 = require('aes256');
const express = require('express');
const web_server = express();

var key = 'LeIdeeMettonoInMotoIlFuturo';
var cipher = aes256.createCipher(key);

async function aes_encryption(plaintext) {
  do{
    var encrypted = await cipher.encrypt(plaintext);
  } while (await validation(encrypted))
  return encrypted;
}

async function validation(string){
  if (string.indexOf("$") != -1 && string.indexOf("&") != -1 && string.indexOf("+") != -1 && string.indexOf(";") != -1 && string.indexOf("?") != -1){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

async function aes_decryption(encrypted){
  var decrypted = await cipher.decrypt(encrypted);
  return decrypted;
}

web_server.get('/', function (request, response) {
  response.send('Write /encryption/:parola_da_codificare or /decryption/:testo_da_decodificare');
})

web_server.get('/encryption/', async function (request, response) {
  var result = await aes_encryption(request.query.code);
  response.send('Your code crypted is: ' + result);
})

web_server.get('/decryption/', async function (request, response) {
  var result = await aes_decryption(request.query.code);
  response.send('Your code decripted is: ' + result);
})

web_server.listen(3000)
```

Comment: You should be sending the code in body else in the headers of the request.

Comment: @DeekshithHegde Is this just a piece of good programming practice advice or a determining factor in the correctness of the code?

Comment: Always it's not a good practice to send senstive data in URL. Apart from that, URL also has limitations and it won't allow you to send special characters in request so for that case you should switch to Post method or send it in headers. The second one being the good option in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `validation()` function.

1. You should return `true` only when you find any one of the symbols in the string. Returning true will keep the while loop on.
2. But you are returning `true` when all the symbols are not present in the string. In that case, you should return `false` so that while loop can break and you can get the last string.

```
function validation(string){

    if(["$","&","+",";","?"].some(v => string.includes(v))){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Take a look at the modified validation function, it should fix the issue and you don't even need async-await for this function.